# Calculation Field referencing field in an separate form

Tags: cognito-forms

Is it possible in a Calculation Field to reference a field in a different form rather than just within the same form?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks like a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask], [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4502/88163)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

At the moment we do not, but this is a feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP).